# Can a Django project backend server run in two environments?

Tags: python, node.js, django

Can a Django project backend server run in two environments?

I have a Django-Rest-Framework project( using `Python` write the project ) as the backend to provide APIs, and now I want to add a application to as a `app` in my backend. The application is written using `node.js`.

Can I use two environments to run the backend project?

Comment: You need both of them to serve as http server? If yes, you should bind different ports (eg, 8000 and 8001) for those two applications to make them work in one server.

Comment: What does this mean? What "two environments"?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Meaning in the backend I want to use python/Django (some apps) and node.js (for another app).